# Solaris kernel parameter equivalence to Linux

Tags: linux, solaris, kernel

I have set the following tcp kernel parameters in Solaris

```
ndd -set /dev/tcp tcp_ip_abort_interval 120000 
ndd -set /dev/tcp tcp_rexmit_interval_max 15000 
ndd -set /dev/tcp tcp_rexmit_interval_min 400 
ndd -set /dev/tcp tcp_keepalive_interval 30000
```

What would be the equivalence in Linux (RedHat) ? I have only found tcp_keepalive_intvl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those you miss, it's for more params to tune up and some of them are part of netfilter:

```
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_syn_sent = 120
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_syn_recv = 60
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established = 432000
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_fin_wait = 120
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close_wait = 60
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_last_ack = 30
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_time_wait = 120
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close = 10
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_max_retrans = 300
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_unacknowledged = 300
```

You have to load connection tracking modules in kernel.

Others to tune up:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries = 5
net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries = 5
net.ipv4.tcp_retries1 = 3
net.ipv4.tcp_retries2 = 15
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 60
```

So you have to calculate values for those param to mimic behaviour you get by setting 4 params to Solaris net stack. Btw check `man 7 tcp` in Linux.